# Xamarin.Android -SDK and User Assembly linking removes property in the 3rd party dll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a strange behavior with android linker. I am using a scheduler tool from Syncfusion. I have added it is all 3 dlls as

`Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms;Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.Android;Syncfusion.SfSchedule.Android;`

as Skip Linking assemblies when I use "SDK and User Assemblies"

But One property of this dll is throwing exception as shown below. Obviously a property called IsYearlySpecific is removed by the linker. I dont know why but I created fresh project and tried same code and it just works fine. Whatever I tried I cant reproduce in a new project.

My original project is quite big with several other package. If anybody can give a suggestion what should I do here without recreating whole entire project.
I tried many times clean-rebuild solution. Deleted obj and bin folders under XF project as well as Android Project. I tried this project in another machine as well.

I contacted their support but they couldnt reproduce either and require a sample project. Since I cant reproduce in a fresh project and I am not able to share my entire source code of original project.
Please give me some advises if any other caching or whatsover exist and I can clean things.

```
{Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Z" field "IsYearlySpecific" in class "Lcom/syncfusion/schedule/RecurrenceProperties;" or its superclasses
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/f3074d2c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceFields.GetFieldID (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, System.String name, System.String signature) [0x00068] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:10972 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String name, System.String sig) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/JNIEnv.g.cs:456 
  at Com.Syncfusion.Schedule.RecurrenceProperties.set_IsYearlySpecific (System.Boolean value) [0x00016] in <e63d7911148e4f5c8433fa067a7eae25>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.Droid.RecurrenceBuilder_Android.Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.IRecurrenceBuilder.RRuleGenerator (Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.RecurrenceProperties formRecurrenceProperties, System.DateTime startTime, System.DateTime endTime) [0x000cd] in <9625327b1ffb4afb82c0a45d09128902>:0 
  at myapp.Pages.ScheduleSamplePage.get_Title () [0x0010c] in C:\Git\myapp\myapp\myapp\Pages\ScheduleSamplePage.cs:48 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldError stack trace ---
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Z" field "IsYearlySpecific" in class "Lcom/syncfusion/schedule/RecurrenceProperties;" or its superclasses
    at md5874faab2802fcbafca06095cc637d65d.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md5874faab2802fcbafca06095cc637d65d.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
}
```

Comment: I have done that already as mentioned above. I thought maybe if there is something under my user profile some other package caches etc

Comment: I need more coffee... `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError` : Do you have Proguard enabled?

Comment: Yes I have.  Clean project has no proguard

Comment: Does it work w/o Proguard enabled? If so, add a proguard `--keep` on that Java class `syncfusion.schedule.*`

Comment: I will try that. Let me ask you another question i added that proguard blindly by follwing articles.  Do I need it indeed if i have linking enabled. Is not same thing?

Comment: The Xamarin linker stripes `IL` code from CIL-based assemblies, Proguard strips Java bit-code (and resources, etc...). Similar function, but Java vs. .Net

Comment: @SushiHangover there is also "Bundle Assemblies into Native Code" option. Do you know if it is possible to use Proguard with this option together?

Comment: Totally separate, that option bundles CIL-based assembles after the linker option if enabled. Proguard is striping dear code from the Java classes

Comment: @SushiHangover you were right. Proguard is removing members. I uncheck proguard and it worked fine but I couldnt figure how to write correct syntax for keep. I tried -keep class Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.** { *; } and it didnt work. as i read the documentation, it looks like keep assembly not exist. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Z" field "IsYearlySpecific" in class "Lcom/syncfusion/schedule/RecurrenceProperties;" or its superclasses

The Java package names will be lowercase, so from the error, I would add the following to a proguard config file that is assigned a **build type** of **`ProguardConfiguration`**

```
-keep class com.syncfusion.** { *; }
-keep class * extends com.syncfusion.** { *; }
```

Note: Make sure that the proguard file you add is NOT a Unicode text file (U+FEFF byte order mark (BOM)) as proguard will fail...

Comment: It really worked but let me understand something please. why none of these below doesnt work. Before I tried them no sucess. 2nd question, Does your one tell me keep everything has syncfusion in name space or class name? 


-keepclassmembers class Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.RecurrenceProperties

-keep public class Syncfusion.SfSchedule.Android.** { *; }

-keep public class Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.** { *; }

-keep public class Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.Android.** { *; }

Comment: @batmaci My example is keeping *everything* in  `com.syncfusion` package(s). All of your examples are using the wrong Java package name, I'm assuming `Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms` is the C# namespace(? I do not use Syncfusion). If you have multiple `com.syncfusion` packages, you could restrict my example further by using just one package `com.syncfusion.schedule.*` or just one class `com.syncfusion.schedule.RecurrenceProperties`,  or one class and its fields `com.syncfusion.schedule.RecurrenceProperties { <fields>; }` and so on.... make sense?

Comment: it means com. Prefix is Java specific?  I mean I am not very much familiar with Java.  Thats why i try to understand the pattern.

Comment: @batmaci Java package names are similar to C# namespaces, so in the the case of `com.syncfusion.schedule.RecurrenceProperties`, `com.syncfusion.schedule` is the package name and `RecurrenceProperties` is the class. Just as C# namespace can be just about any name, so can Java but they are lowercase, names follow hierarchical naming pattern and classes in the same package can access private/protected members....

Comment: Ah ok i Just saw that it is already written in the exception message that it Lcom/syncfusion/schedule but why is Lcom? What is it standing for? Sorry for digging into it. Just try to understand if next time i have similar issue to figure out myself